# Javascript - copy contents of div and add to sessionStorage

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, session-storage

I have a div called `main`. I want to copy its contents and save them in sessionStorage. How do I do this?

```
<div id='main'>

    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>
    <div class='content'>Content</div>

</div>

<script>

    var data = $('#main').geteverything(); // Copy everything in the div main
    var name = "main";
    sessionStorage.setItem(name, data);

</script>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Have you tried your code? Does `geteverything()` exist? And, if so, what is its code? If not, use `.innerHTML` instead.

Comment: Get everything does not exist

Answer (score -1):

You can user the innerHTML property from the HTML elements like this:

```js
const name = "main";
const data = document.getElementById(name).innerHTML;
sessionStorage.setItem(name, data);
```

```html
<div id='main'>
        <div class='content'>Content</div>
        <div class='content'>Content</div>
        <div class='content'>Content</div>
        <div class='content'>Content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: We tend not to provide answers to poor questions that shouldn't be posted here in the first place as it tends to just attract more poor questions. Additionally, your answer does little more than repeat what was already in the comments.

Comment: How is this a poor question?

Comment: I don´t think is a poor question, maybe would be better to explicitly say that the function .geteverything(); was just an example or  if not, pasting that function code, nevertheless I found it clear enoguh to understand your problem and give you a solution.